# Showing print integer with pattern in java

Tags: java

I wanna ask you something about my code. I want to display output as below:

```
 2  3  4  1
 6  7  8  5
10 11 12  9
14 15 16 13
```

But the output what is shown:

```
2  3  4  1
6  3  0 -3
2 -1 -4 -7
```

-2 -5 -8-11

Here is my current code:

```
for(int i=0; i<4; i++){
        for(int j=0; j<4; j++){
            System.out.printf("%3d", number);
            if(j==2){
                plus=-3;
            }
            number+=plus;
        }
        number+=8;

        System.out.println("");
    }
```

Can you tell me what's wrong with it? Thank you

Comment: What is number?

Comment: It'd be helpful to know what these numbers represent (in the desired output) or how they are defined. Please extend your question with such a description.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to reset `plus` to `1` at the end of each iteration of the outer loop. See the below code in action [here](https://ideone.com/zY82lm).

```
int number = 2;
int plus = 1;
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
        System.out.printf("%3d", number);
        if (j == 2) {
            plus = -3;
        }
        number += plus;
    }
    number += 8;
    plus = 1;
    System.out.println("");
}
```